# 2 different do-while loop construct in Java?

Tags: java, do-while

## Note: please see edit on bottom!

I always only know do-while loop in Java in this shape:

```
do {

} while(condition);
```

<strike>Today, while preparing for Oracle Certified Java exam, I'm shocked to find out this:</strike>

```
do while (condition) {

}
```

It compiles without problem. I couldn't find the construct in language specs. Could someone point me to a reference? Also what's the difference? Why have 2?

## **Edit:**

Appologies for not posting the complete code snippet and claiming something that's not true!

The second loop doesn't compile. This does:

```
  do while (true) System.out.println("Got me!");
    while (true);
```

And see accepted answer for explanation on why it does!

I hope this question helps forth comers who fall in the same trap.

Comment: No, this loop is not valid, try it and it isn't compiled

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on something that is simply not true.

Comment: @Charles W -  which java version/IDE do you see this compile under?

Comment: I think that QA just has confused second loop with `while (statement) {...}`

Comment: @mattfreake Java 1.8, IntelliJ 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do {

} while(condition);
```

is a "do-while" loop, driven by the `condition`. It compiles just fine and the `do`' body will be executed *at least* once.

The second snippet, however (if competed to compile, because yours doesn't), is equal to:

```
do {
   while (condition) {

   }
} while(otherCondition);
```

Here we have a nested `while` loop within the `do`'s body. Omitting the `do`'s body brackets `{}` can lead to confusion.

Comment: No, this loop is not valid, try it

Comment: I'm talking about original `do while (condition) { ... }` loop from the question

Comment: Quote from my answer: "*if competed to compile, because yours doesn't*". The statement "*it compiles just fine*" is regarding the first loop.

Comment: With my deep respect to you, your answer gives impression that there isn't any problem with question in topic. But it simply should be closed.

Comment: BTW I'm **not** downvoter )

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code will not be compiled, it gives the error:

```
error: while expected
        }
         ^
 error: illegal start of expression
}
^
 error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
error: reached end of file while parsing
4 errors
```

So this loop is not valid and java compiler work as is actually described in [JLS, ch 14.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.13):

> The do statement executes a Statement and an Expression repeatedly
>   until the value of the Expression is false.

```
DoStatement:
    do Statement while ( Expression ) ;
```